# How getting the name of a control which placed in other Application?

Tags: windows, spy++

how I can receive the name of a control which placed in other application?

comments: with "Microsoft Spy++" I can receive the "class name" of a control(for example TButton, TrzEdit, TAdvSmoothButton ... etc.) but I need to receive tha actual name of a control(for example: Button1, Button2 ... etc.).

can you help me???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need the name?

Using Spy++ you can get both the dialog handle and the handle of the control you are interested in and then you can use them in your code.

e.g.

```
UINT WINAPI GetDlgItemText(
  __in   HWND hDlg,
  __in   int nIDDlgItem,
  __out  LPTSTR lpString,
  __in   int nMaxCount
);
```

Check out MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645489(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Answer for: Why you need the name?

Comment: I have a very very large source code and It's Executable file which written in bcb. it using a very huge varius of thirdparty components. in new version of this app I want write It in Delphi 2010. So I Need to access source code of it. many of used components which used in older version are not free. older version of this app programmed very bad. for example in it's source code I can See very bad component names(ex: button768, button1345 and etc...). so I can't open this project in bcb. by this reasons I need to undrestand which source code used by a special component.

Comment: Look for a string that may appear in this dialog which uses the control you are looking for, or the dialog/window title.